cover/mask the anchor holes after removing the washing basins
I have changed the wall-mounted washing basins in the bathroom for the vessel ones and am now left with 4 ugly holes (photo enclosed, but only 2 of those holes are visible). I have partially filled them with left-over grouting mortar and would like to know some ideas on how to best cover/mask/camouflage those holes.
Thank you!

Cannot really see, but adding a back splash might hide them.  An artist might match the tile finish, but covering up or replacing are the usual choices for holes/damage in tiles.

Fill the holes with unsanded grout. Use a Plastic spreader to make the fill even with the surface of the tile.
Let the grout dry overnight. Wipe the surface lightly with a scrubbing pad similar to those needed for pots and pans. Wipe the dust from the surface.
Get a little black and white latex enamel paint. Mix the 2 colors until you get a satisfactory match of color. Having some blue helps with the match as well. Then dab the paint on the tile. DO NOT brush. A dabbing application does better at blending the color.
